# Unable to connect my jsp page with ms access

Tags: java, jsp, odbc

I could not connect my jsp page with ms access
it says

```
"java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

I have created a dsn but still the problem is same..

I searched the net extensively but couldn't rectify....

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:students");
```

This line is causing exception.... 
I selected the data source in the DNS still too.... I'm using Access....

Here is everything:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<%

PreparedStatement pstm;
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

//connection object created using DriverManager class
//employee is the name of the database
Connection connect =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:employee");

//creating prepared statement object pstm so that query can be sent to database
pstm=connect.prepareStatement("insert into employee values(?,?,?,?)");
pstm.setString(1,"5");
pstm.setString(2,"parth");
pstm.setString(3,"parth");
pstm.setString(4,"10000");
//execute method to execute the query
pstm.executeUpdate();
out.println("Record Added Successfully");
pstm.close();

connect.close();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can test your datasource config by creating a new empty file (pretty much anywhere, desktop will work fine) with any name you like and changing the extension to .udl

When you change the extension the icon changes. Then double click it and you should see `students` datasource in the first combo (`Use data source name`), select it and click `Test Connection`.

If everything works out up to this point then your datasource is ok, and the problem is with your code, which should be something like this http://www.kodejava.org/examples/151.html